# i have to two choose two element from an array such that there lcm is maximum

Tags: c++

1. simple solution will be  is to make pair of each element and find
   max LCM but it will have time complexity of O(n^2)

   is there any other solution to reduce the time complexity

   example

   array=12, 9, 1, 8

   LCM(12,9)=36

   LCM(12,1)=12

   LCM(12,8)=24

   LCM(9,1)=9

   LCM(9,8)=72

   LCM(1,8)=8

   So, maximum value is 72.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;
void lcm(int a[],int n)
{
  int i,j,k,l,s,lc=INT_MIN;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
      s=a[i]<a[j]?a[i]:a[j];
      l=a[i]>a[j]?a[i]:a[j];
      for(k=0;k<s;k++)
      {
        if(l*(k+1)%s==0&&lc<l*(k+1))
        {
          lc=l*(k+1);
          break;
        }
      }
     }
   }
   cout<<"max lcm possible for a pair is= "<<lc;
 }
 int main()
 {
  int a[20],n,i;
   cout<<"enter n= ";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"enter an array= ";
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cin>>a[i];
   }
   lcm(a,n);
 }
```

** this code is made in c++ without suggest for optimisation**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, after reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), try to review your question explaining your solution. Adding explanations and limitations will make your solution much more valuable and you will have more chance of having *up* votes.